# Can SnowFlake be used as a source endpoint in Data Migration Service of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-dms

I am trying to use AWS DMS Database Migration Service along with Snowflake as a source database. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

All I could see options for IBMDB2, MySQL, SQL Server, Amazon Aurora, Oracle, SAP Sybase etc. But not for Snowflake.

Can ODBC string for SnowFlake be put in as a source endpoint ? Or any workaround

Answer (score 3):

Because DMS doesn't support Snowflake as destination yet so I think you could use S3 as target then use

- Snowflake bulkload  to load data from S3 https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-create-stage.html
- Snowpipe to do continuous loading.